# How to test compliance for Azure "Endpoint Security" policy

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-policy, azure-security

I'm relatively new to Microsoft Azure. I was trying to implement some of the policy assignments, built-in in Azure. One of the policies there is : "Endpoint protection solution should be installed on virtual machine scale sets".
When I deploy this from the security center and set my scope to the resource group under the subscription, I'm not able to see compliant or non-compliant resources after the policy is assigned.

> For example, under the rg I have created two virtual machines, VM1 and VM2 respectively,  one without any endpoint protection solution installed, and the other with Microsoft Antimalware extension installed. I expect to see these resources and their compliance states for the above mentioned policy ( whether they are compliant or non-compliant ). But currently it only shows 0 out of 0 resources.

What changes do I need to make ? For example, do I need to change anything about the way I'm assigning this policy ? Please do suggest.

Comment: it might take a few hours to take effect. Please wait and see if it occurs later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [evaluation triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/get-compliance-data#evaluation-triggers), it takes around 30 minutes for the assignment to be applied to the defined scope. You may need to wait for a long time.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nancy...indeed it was so !